# Is AWS Lambda using Elastic IP?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

First my question: are AWS Lambda "instances" using EIP?

My background:

I'm using lambda as solution to reduce my application load of certain task(download youtube videos).

In the past I was having problems trying to do this very thing in my ec2 instances, in which I used them with EIP, which always returned limit exceed message, and prompted human captcha verification. I solved this at that time by using the instances without EIP and worked like a charm.

Now using lambda for certain videos it throws me ***Error: Code 150: The uploader has not made this video available in your country.*** and I double checked that the video was not blocked for US, and it wasn't. So I decided to go back and test with an instance with EIP, and that was it, the same message that was been returned in my lambda function.

It seems to be a change from youtube, because around 3-4 months ago the error when using EIP was limit exceed, but now it turned to country blocked issue. So it's like lambda uses EIP or alike service which youtube doesn't seems to like.

PS: I'm running my lambda function with nodejs and download the videos with ytdl-core btw.
PS2: I asked this very question in aws forums but no luck so far in a week or so. So I decided to try asking here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Lambda is not the same an as EC2 instance. It runs on containers within the AWS infrastructure. Traffic would "appear" to be coming from certain IP addresses, but there is no way to configure which IP address is used.

It is possible that the range of "IP addresses from which Lambda appears to come" is not correctly updated in the geo-database used by the video service, and it thinks they are located in a different location.

Bottom line: There is nothing you can configure.

Comment: I did a workaround using a proxy for this matter but I didn't had the reason of that behavior until now. thanks